# Select from database immediately after writing

Tags: mysql, select

I need to select the last row inserted into a database immediately after writing it. I have a form that, when submitted, generates an auto-incremented key. I then need to select this key so that I can email it to the submitter. I tried querying the db AFTER executing the insert, but i don't get any results. I've double checked my queries and they are sound by themselves. Am I missing something? My code looks like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$email."')";
$result = $db->query($query);
$query = "SELECT MAX(userid) as userid FROM users";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

My problem is that the second `$result` doesn't return any results.

Comment: So I tried `$query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";` and it returns the error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string" when I tried to run the query.

Comment: Yup, I'm retarded. `$result` is not a string, and therefore cannot be `echo`ed outright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value like this:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: OK, I tried that and got "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string" when I tried to echo it.

Answer (score 2):

$query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";

Answer (score 1):

Use this function, it selects the last inserted `auto_increment` id

```
mysql_insert_id();
```